# Can we manipulate "System information" that comes with Windows?

Tags: windows

If I want to check a system's hardware like hard disk capacity, RAM etc...Is it better to check in CMOS settings or in "System Information"?

Is there any possibility to manipulate the  `System information` data that comes with Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the memory amount listed under 'System Information' may not reflect the physical memory in the machine (Related to using having more memory than the 32-bit OS can handle - If you are running a 32-bit OS)

I'd recommend [cpu-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) - A freeware utility that gathers information on some of the main devices of your system. CPU-Z does not need to be installed.